# Pass parameter to side_effect function for patching in unittest.mock

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest, python-mock

I'm using `patch` from `unittest.mock` to change the behavior of a remote API call in my test.

I have three different functions that return three different `json` files that represent the mock data to be returned from the API. For each mock api call, I am setting `side_effect` to be one of these functions. This pattern isn't DRY, but I don't know how to pass a parameter to a `side_effect` function.

The three mock api call functions look like this:

```
def mock_api_call_1():
    with open('path/to/mock_1.json') as f:
        mock_data = json.load(f)
    return mock_data
```

Here's my test

```
class MyTest(TestCase):

    def test_api(self):

        with patch('mymodule.utils.api_call', side_effect=mock_api_call_1):
            do_crud_operations()
            self.assertEqual(MyModel.objects.all().count(), 10)

        with patch('mymodule.utils.api_call', side_effect=mock_api_call_2):
            do_crud_operations()
            self.assertEqual(MyModel.objects.all().count(), 11)
```

How can I refactor this code to be able to pass a parameter to the `side_effect` (`mock_call(1)` instead of `mock_call_1`).

From the [unittest docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html), I see that:

> side_effect: A function to be called whenever the Mock is called. See
>   the side_effect attribute. Useful for raising exceptions or
>   dynamically changing return values. The function is called with the
>   same arguments as the mock, and unless it returns DEFAULT, the return
>   value of this function is used as the return value.

I see that the function passed to `side_effect` takes the same arguments as the mock, but I'm still not sure how best to use mock to accomplish this. I'll eventually want to add more test cases, so I don't want to be hard-coding different `mock_api_call` functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a lambda function:

```
from unittest import TestCase, main
from unittest.mock import Mock, patch
import sys

def mock_api_call(x):
    print(x)

class MyTest(TestCase):
    def test_api(self):
        with patch('sys.exit',
                    side_effect=lambda x: mock_api_call(x)) as m:
            m(0)
            sys.exit(0)

            m(1)
            sys.exit(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way to do this is to set `side_effect` to a function that returns a function.

```
def mock_call(num):
    def wrapper():
        with open(f"path/to/mock_{num}.json") as f:
            data = json.load(f)
        return data
    return wrapper
```

Now I can pass `mock_call(1)` to `side_effect` and it will behave as expected.